# Equivalent Definitions of Gaussian Process?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, gaussian

The Gaussian process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ ($T=[0,1]$ for example) is usually defined using its finite-dimensional distribution. I came across this statement many times: linear operator (not necessarily bounded) transformation of Gaussian process is also Gaussian. [See[1](http://user.it.uu.se/~carji475/pdfs/linconstgps.pdf),[2](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~garnett/cse515t/spring_2017/files/lecture_notes/11.pdf),[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03134)]Thus, obviously, any bounded linear operator on Gaussian process is Gaussian. I am wondering if there exists another equivalent definition: $X_t$ is Gaussian process iff for any bounded linear operator $A: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ ($\mathcal{H}$ is the Hilbert space where $X_t$ lies in), $A X_t$ is a $d$-dimensional Gaussian. Any proof or reference on the statement I read? Is my guess on equivalent definition correct?

Comment: A discontinuous (unbounded) linear functional of a Gaussian process need not be Gaussian; indeed, typically it won't even be measurable, so saying it's "Gaussian" has no meaning.

Comment: @NateEldredge Any reference on this? And if the operator is bounded and linear, does the equivalence hold?

Comment: But if you start with bounded linear functionals, the equivalence is clear.  One direction is trivial by taking $d=1$.  For the other direction, it's an elementary exercise to show that a *finite dimensional* random vector is Gaussian iff every linear functional of it is Gaussian (easy with Fourier transforms, for instance); and note that if $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear then $f \circ A$ is a bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256541/measurable-linear-functionals-are-also-continuous-on-separable-banach-spaces.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. But I still don't understand why bounded linear operator on Gaussian process is Gaussian. Can you explain more?